# Python to csv column break

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, export-to-csv

I am parsing +1000 txt (Edgar) files with Python and need to transfer some fields into a .csv file. I require 4 fields: file form, file date, company name, and central index key (i.e. firm identification number). To do so, I wrote:

```
with open('exemptionss1.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    wr = csv.writer(out_file)
    wr.writerow(["file_form", "filedate", "coname", "cik"])  # Headlines in  top row
    for i in range(0, len(exemptions), 4):
        wr.writerow(exemptions[i: i + 4])
```

where "exemptions" is the vector variable where all parsed information is. Took it from Sublime Text's result panel:

```
exemptions = ['S-1', '20090820', '\t\t\t\tDOLLAR GENERAL CORP', '\t\t0000029534', 'S-1/A', '20021114', '\t\t\t\tCONSTAR INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000029806', '\t\t\t\tCONSTAR FOREIGN HOLDINGS INC', '\t\t0001178543', '\t\t\t\tCONSTAR PLASTICS LLC', '\t\t0001178541', '\t\t\t\tDT INC', '\t\t0001178539', '\t\t\t\tBFF INC', '\t\t0001178538', '\t\t\t\tCONSTAR INC', '\t\t0001178537', 'S-1', '20020523', '\t\t\t\tCONSTAR INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000029806', 'S-1', '20051123', '\t\t\t\tEXCO RESOURCES INC', '\t\t0000316300', 'S-1', '20061221', '\t\t\t\tEXCO RESOURCES INC', '\t\t0000316300', 'S-1/A', '20140327', '\t\t\t\tAlly Financial Inc.', '\t\t0000040729', 'S-1', '20110331', '\t\t\t\tAlly Financial Inc.', '\t\t0000040729', 'S-1', '20040319', '\t\t\t\tDIGIRAD CORP', '\t\t0000707388', 'S-1', '20040408', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761', 'S-1', '20041027', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761', 'S-1', '20050630', '\t\t\t\tSEALY CORP', '\t\t0000748015', 'S-1', '20140512', '\t\t\t\tCITIZENS FINANCIAL GROUP INC/RI', '\t\t0000759944']
```

If every .txt file would only contain each field one time, the above would work (it essentially asks python to create a new row every 4 "instances"). However, that is not the case, and a sample of the .csv output file looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, row 1 is just fine. The problem is in the second .txt file that contains several repetitions of the fields I require and, correctly after 4 instances, it starts a new row. It's not until row 6 (counting the headers) that the new file_form ("S-1") appears again.

What I would like is that every file would be the starting of each .csv row. Importantly, the file form field (I only have "S-1" or "S-1/A" forms) never gets repeated. In other words, the second .txt S-1/A file should include all variables in the same row, and leave row 3 with the next .txt file. Something like this:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It seems like the problem has little to do with writing to CSV, and more to do with how the `exemptions` list gets built, and whether it's useful for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. I edited the post to make it more explicit. You're certainly right that I am creating only one list for the whole .txt files parsing exercise... Do you know how to separate each file? So that I would have as many ['S-1',....] as files? I guess this would make it easier...

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over how `exemptions` is built, that would be the place to start. But that would also be an almost entirely different question.

If you don't have control over `exemptions`, then you could do something like this:

```
# `exemptions` is a concatenation of info extracted from multiple
# Edgar files. The contribution from each file starts with a line
# that gives the 'file form', which in this case is always either
# 'S-1' or 'S-1/A'.
#
# Find the positions where the info from each Edgar file starts.
start_positions = [
    p
    for (p, line) in enumerate(exemptions)
    if line.startswith('S-1')
]

# The number of start-positions we've found is the number of Edgar
# files that contributed to `exemptions`.
n_files = len(start_positions)

# Each file's info in `exemptions` runs from its start-position
# up to but not including the start position of the next file's info
# (or to the end of `exemptions`, if it's the last file).
#
# Isolate each file's info
for i in range(n_files):
    start_position = start_positions[i]
    if i+1 < n_files:
        end_position = start_positions[i+1]
    else:
        end_position = len(exemptions)
    print(exemptions[start_position:end_position])
```

I didn't do the export-to-CSV because that isn't really the heart of your problem, and you shouldn't have any trouble adapting the code you've shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. You were right with catching the issue. I posted the solution I finally used.

Answer (score 0):

Michael was right in that the problem was in the list "exemptions". I created a new list including all sublists starting with 'S-1' and then use this one to write the csv file.

```
exemptions2 = [s.strip('|').split('|') for s in re.split(r'(?=S-1)', '|'.join(exemptions)) if s]
```

And then just simply write the csv file with a standard command:

```
with open('exemptionss1.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    wr = csv.writer(out_file)
    wr.writerow(["file_form", "filedate", "coname", "cik"])  # Headlines in  top row
    wr.writerows(exemptions2)
```

Hope this can help other Python users.